# How do I *exclude*

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have a dataframe (data) which includes a lot of dates. I want to lop off everything from before 1970. I can create a list of indices that are before 1970:

```
tmp <- which(data$data < '1970-01-01')
[1]  13446 102876 141199
```

and I want to create a new table that drops out those three rows. Something like:

```
data.after.1970 <- data[!tmp, ]
```

I know I could create a vector of all the incidents *after* 1970 and match against it with:

```
tmp <- which(data$data > '1970-01-01')
data.after.1970 <- data[tmp, ]
```

But I am wondering what syntax I would use to exclude items.

**UPDATE**

I finally just did this:

```
tmp <- which(data$data > as.Date('1970-01-01'))
data.after.1970 <- data[tmp, ]
```

and took a closer look at it. `which(data$data < as.Date('1970-01-01'))` gets three results, but `nrow(data) - nrow(data.after.1970)` shows that I dropped 45 rows. `summary(datae$date)` cleared that up:

```
summary(data$date)
        Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max.         NA's 
"1933-07-01" "1989-01-25" "1992-07-09" "1992-05-03" "1996-06-10" "2006-09-14"         "42"
```

Since my goal was to get a second dataset so I could compare my results if I exclude those with bad dates, I actually do want to drop those with NA values as well.

I *still* want to know what syntax I would use to exclude some numeric vector rather than include it.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `subset`?

Comment: if you find yourself using `which` while sub-setting, you're probably making your live more difficult than it needs to be.  Instead, subset using the `[` function.  `data[data$data > '1970-01-01',]` Aside from that advice... I'm not terribly sure what the question is...

Comment: Amanda, are you asking what is the difference between finding the rows **not wanted** and **excluding**, versus finding the rows **wanted** and **including**?

Comment: @JasonMorgan That's another approach that would work.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I think I'm asking what syntax I'd use to to exclude the rows not wanted. But I was having trouble phrasing it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was actually pretty simple.

```
data.after.1970 <- data[-tmp, ]
```

will create a new frame, `data.after.1970` that includes all the rows from `data` except those which match the indexes in  `tmp`.

Answer (score 5):

`which` returns a numeric vector for the items that are TRUE in the the evaluation of a logical expression or in a logical vector itself. It is also possible to use negative indexing to remove items. In your case that might look like:

```
tmp <- data[ which(data$data < '1970-01-01') ,  ]
```

I.e.  return all rows of the dataframe, "data" where the "data" column is less than "1970-01-01". Your really should learn to use more specific names than "data". Not only will you create confusion by having hte same name for an object and a element with that object, but there is also a function "data". So how is your poor audience supposed to know what you meant when you wrote than code 10 months ago.

To address those nay-sayers above who do not like the use of `which` I would answer that it avoids the problem that the "[" function will return all rows for which either the condition is TRUE or is NA. You can use `subset` which has the same advantage but it is not advised for use in programming, only for interactive use. You could do it the way that subset does it and add a clause that eliminates the NA values:

```
tmp <- data[ data$data < '1970-01-01 & !is.na(data$data) , ]
```

... and I would argue that the version using `which` is "cleaner" than that alternative. There is a downside to `which` which arises in the case where no values are TRUE and you are using negative indexing, in which case, contrary to expectation using `dfrm[-which(condition) , ]` will not give you what you want but rather an empty vector. So the rule is: use `which` but not with negative indexing.

Comment: Well, there you go, I learnt something today.

Comment: @Dwin, I'm curious why subset should be avoided? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637321/why-should-subset-be-avoided-in-programming-r

Comment: @DWin FWIW, I actually use much more specific names but I tend to switch to something generic when I'm asking questions here. My real dataframes are closer to `fatal.overdose.incidents` -- but I figure that would be a distraction.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Comment: Thank you @GSee!  @Mnel had pointed me to that question as well. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

To explain a little more, if you run:

```
data$date > '1970-01-01'
```

you will see it returns a logical vector of `TRUE/FALSE` which you can use to select the required rows. It works as in this example:

```
test <- 1:3
test[c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)]
# result
[1] 1 3
```

As @DWin notes in his answer, there are some caveats when you have `NA` values, which will also be returned as well as the `TRUE` values. As in:

```
test <- c(NA,1:3)
test > 2
# result
[1]    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE
test[test>2]
# result
[1] NA  3
```

The `which` statement returns all the `TRUE` indices only, which avoids the issue with `NA` values.

```
test <- c(NA,1:3)

which(test>2)
# result - the fourth value of test is > 2
[1] 4

> test[4]
# result - return the fourth value of test
[1] 3

test[which(test>2)]
# result - return the fourth value of test as the 
# which statement has identified it is > 2
[1] 3
```

As an aside, I'm gathering you would probably actually need to do something like:

```
data$date > as.Date('1970-01-01')
```

...to get your example working properly. This is assuming of course your `date` column is also actually a `Date` object and not just plain text.